# is there any sample of using oAuth to get hotmail contact list?

Tags: oauth, contacts, hotmail

is there any sample of using oAuth to get hotmail contact list?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they support OAuth.  They seem to use [Windows Live ID Delegated Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287637.aspx), which is a similar concept, but non-standard.  They do have samples for both the [authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287665.aspx) and [contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463974%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx) APIs, though.

Answer (score 1):

CloudSponge can do it for you.

http://www.cloudsponge.com/test-drive

We've also written up a complete timeline of the changes to Microsoft's DelAuth/OAuth APIs over the last few years for anyone who's interested.

http://inside.cloudsponge.com/stories/2013/11/29/300-percent-increase-in-outlook.com-import-conversions.html

(In case I didn't make it obvious enough, I work for CloudSponge)

Answer (score 0):

You can use socialauth library for this. 
URL for the same is  http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/